# regular expression for find replace modification

Tags: regex, eclipse

I wanted to use regular expressions in **eclipse** to adept code to a software update.

instead of

`{$CFG->prefix}example1.xy`

the code needs to be:

`{example1}.xy`

to work.

another example would be:

`{$CFG->prefix}example2.foo`

>

`{example2}.foo`

constant parts are : `{$CFG->prefix}`; `.`

i tried the following (i used whitespaces to make reading easier):

Find: `\{\$CFG-\>prefix\} ([a-z]|[0-9])* \. ([a-z]|[0-9])*`

Which will find the requested String. I struggle in replacing it.

i can use `,/1`to store the result of the regex and use it in the replacement (right?) but i am not sure how i can modify/manipulate this result.

thanks for any help.

Comment: i am going to accept the answer that gets voted higher because i find both equally appealing. Waiting a few days for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following search and replace :

**Find**: `\{\$CFG->prefix\}([a-z0-9]*)\.([a-z0-9]*)`

**Replace with** : `{\1}.\2`

Using the above the following :

[image: Before]     BECOMES     [image: After]

**[Here](http://youtu.be/QTKSkPbzcEA)** is a quick screen-cast to show this in action.

#### Changes made to the OP's Find reg-ex

In order to get the above find-replace to work, I had to make the following changes to the OP's find expression :

1. Removed whitespaces.
2. Moved the Greedy Match modifier inside the groups : i.e.  `([...]*)` instead of `([...])*`
3. Corrected the character set : i.e `[a-z0-9]` instead of `[a-z]|[0-9]`
4. Introduced another Group which captures the part after the period. This however is not strictly needed but may be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the correct `Find` expression. Try it out.

Comment: @Wandang, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the 'Tick' mark next to it like so : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: i wrote a comment on that above. your answer is nicely presented while stema's answer includes a useful hint (shortening the regular expression). that's why i am not sure which is better for the community.

Comment: @Wandang, I have updated my answer to reflect the changes I made to your Find expression and have also reformatted my answer to re-organize the content. Have also added a screen-cast to show the Find and replace in action.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
\{\$CFG-\>prefix\}([a-z0-9]*)\.
```

and replace with

```
{\1}.
```

1. I am not sure why you do have the whitespaces in your regex, I removed them.
2. the quantifier `*` should be inside your group, otherwise you will have only the last matched character in `\1` and not the complete word.
3. Since you don't want to replace the last part, you don't need to match and replace it.

Comment: i added whitespaces on purpose to make my question more clear and easier to access what i did. :)
your advices are very helpful.
thanks for your answer!

Comment: This answer is a bit cleaner and more straightforward, although the answer from AshutoshJindal is very thoroughly explained.